# Getting error with my options for date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am new to rails and getting the following errors with my date_select options:

> syntax error, unexpected tLABEL ...ct :date_of_birth, (start_year:
>   Time.now.year - 120), (end_y...
>
> syntax error, unexpected tLABEL ...ime.now.year - 120), (end_year:
>   Time.now.year - 13), { :orde...

Here is my code:

```
f.date_select :date_of_birth, (start_year: Time.now.year - 120), (end_year: Time.now.year - 13), { :order => [:month, :day:year], :prompt => { :day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year' }}
```

Please help!

Comment: I just figured it out - for those who have the same problem look below:

Comment: f.date_select :date_of_birth, { start_year: Time.now.year - 18, end_year: Time.now.year - 105 }, { :order => [:month, :day, :year], :prompt => { :day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year' } }

Comment: Switching the order like the following will keep the order day, month, year.                                                           f.date_select :date_of_birth, { :order => [:month, :day, :year], :prompt => { :day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year' }, start_year: Time.now.year - 18, end_year: Time.now.year - 105 }